# I can't find a regex that will delete a group of lines where the starting and ending lines contain curly braces

Tags: regex, sed, curly-braces

I have many files with lines that begin with main followed by a left curly brace and end with a line containing a right curly brace. I want to remove these lines:

```
main {
        top:190px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:70%
}
```

I've tried commands like this where I escape the curly braces:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '/^main.*\{/,/^\}/d' {} +
```

and gotten error messages like this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

When I don't escape the curly braces, I don't get an error message but it doesn't remove the lines.

I'm using GNU sed version 4.7 on a system running GNU bash version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Regarding `When I don't escape the curly braces, I don't get an error message but it doesn't remove the lines.` - If `sed -i '/^main.*{/,/^}/d'` doesn't remove the block in your question then the block doesn't look like that in your real data.

Answer (score 2):

The *`Invalid preceding regular expression`* error is caused by the *invalid* regular expression you used. Since there is no `-E` flag, your sed command is interpreted with the POSIX BRE regex rules, and `\{` / `\}` are used to define *range quantifiers* (also, known as limiting or interval quantifiers).

Thus, all you need is either to add `-E` option,

```sh
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -E -i '/^main.*\{/,/^\}/d' {} +
```

Or, remove eascapes from `{` and `}`:

```sh
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '/^main.*{/,/^}/d' {} +
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/hDmRXA).

Of course, if you need to match `{` only if there are just whitespace chars between `main` and `{`, replace `/^main.*{/` with `/^main[[:space:]]*{/` (POSIX BRE).

Answer (score 1):

You may try that:

```
^[ \t]*main[ \t]*\{[^{}]+\}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4TfOxp/1)

Comment: Based on your tips about escaping, I got this to work:
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '/^main[ \t]*{/,/^}/d' {} +

Thanks